# Angular scroll to top component in one place

Tags: angular

My app has several long pages and I made a scroll to top component, to make it convenient for the user. Meanwhile I have up to 20 places, where I have to put the component. Wouldn't it be better to put the component in one place only? I removed the component from all templates and put it only in the app.component.html instead. It works, but I wonder if this is a good way, or is there another solution for this? How do you guys solve this problem?

Comment: Even if the question isn't on topic for SO, I'd personally say that a "scroll to top" button should be fixed on either lower edge when I scrolled down a considerable amount.

Comment: This is exactly what my app-scroll-to-top component does. My question is whether it is OK to place this component in the app.component.html.

Comment: That only really depends on your site layout but won't make much of a difference. If you have for example a `sidebar` and a `content` component in your `app.html`, I'd put it in the `content.html`, since you really only need the scrolling functionality there. you can also put it in the `app.html` and absolutely position it, probably doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: The position is set to fixed. Since I don't use a content component, I will leave the app-scroll-to-top component in the app.component.html. Thanks a lot Mike.S!